# Why do I receive an error at this join tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM T AS T1 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT * 
              FROM T 
              WHERE T.CATEGORY = T1.CATEGORY 
              ORDER BY CATEGORY DESC 
              LIMIT 10)
```

and I receive this

> "Unknown column 'T1.CATEGORY' in 'where clause'".

Why?

---

**Update:**
My purpose of this is to get 10 posts of any category.

Comment: There is no Category column in your T1

Answer (score 1):

Because T1 is not visible from within the subquery.

Your JOIN also serves no purpose and/or you probably forgot the JOIN condition.

Answer (score 0):

In JOIN condition should use **ON** keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM T AS T1 
  CROSS JOIN SELECT * FROM T ON T.CATEGORY = T1.CATEGORY 
               ORDER BY CATEGORY DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: ITYM `... CROSS JOIN T ON ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get 10 posts of each category you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, Post
FROM (
    SELECT a.CATEGORY, a.Post, count(*) as rn
    FROM #T a
    JOIN #T b ON a.CATEGORY = b.CATEGORY AND a.Post >= b.Post
    GROUP BY a.CATEGORY, a.Post) dt
WHERE rn < 11;
```